# How to disable the cursor in QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I am now using QTextEdit with qt virtual keyboard, and I face an issue with QTextEdit

I want to disable the textcursor in QTextEdit. I tried to use

```
setCursorWidth(0);
```

The textcursor does disappear. But when I use arabic keybaord, there will be a small arrow blinking up there

like this:

[image]

Is there any way to disable that blinking cursor?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is a Qt bug which is reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57692). As a workaround you can have your custom class which inherits from `QTextEdit` and re-implement `keyPressEvent` event:

```
class TextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
public:
    TextEdit(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QTextEdit(parent) {
        setReadOnly(true);
    }
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) {
        setReadOnly(false);
        QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
        setReadOnly(true);
    }
};
```

This will also hide the cursor in Right to left languages.

Comment: Hi Nejat, thanks to your comment. But I'm also using qt virtual keybaord now. I'm trying to use virtaul keybaord to type some arabic onto the QTextEdit. It seems that when I set "setReadOnly(true)", then I can not activate qt virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a QProxyStyle, so all the widgets will be affected without the need to inherit from that class.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class CursorStyle: public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    int pixelMetric(QStyle::PixelMetric metric, const QStyleOption *option = nullptr, const QWidget *widget = nullptr) const override
    {
        if(metric == PM_TextCursorWidth)
            return 0;
        return  QProxyStyle::pixelMetric(metric, option, widget);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CursorStyle *style = new CursorStyle(a.style());
    a.setStyle(style);
    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(&w);
    lay->addWidget(new QLineEdit);
    lay->addWidget(new QTextEdit);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment! I think the class you implemented did similar things as `setCursorWidth(0)` ? (`if(metric == PM_TextCursorWidth) return 0;`) However, I can still see the blinking arrow after using this. And by the way, I'm using qt virtual keyboard to type arabic, not the hardware keybaord on laptop/computer.